# Sorting not working in display tag

Tags: java, struts, displaytag

In the below code i have to sort balance column in display tag using sortable=true, but it is not working, when i define this value in bean for formatting and place the currency symbol(getting the currency symbol from session object).

```
<% String strCurrency=(String)session.getAttribute("strCurrency"); %>

    <display:table id="data1" name="invprbmList" requestURI=""  pagesize="10" export="true" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td><display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name">Invoice</display:setProperty>
     <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name">Invoices</display:setProperty>
     <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.some_items_found"><span class="pagebanner"> {0} Invoices found, displaying {2} to {3}. </span></display:setProperty>              
     <bean:define id="invoiceNo"><bean:write name="data1" property="invoiceNo"/></bean:define>
     <bean:define id="invAmt"><bean:write name="data1" property="invAmount" format="#,##,##0.00"/></bean:define>
     <bean:define id="balance"><bean:write name="data1" property="balance" format="#,##,##0.00"/></bean:define>

     <display:column  title="Invoice No." sortable="true" media="html" class="l" headerClass="hl"><a href="GetInvoiceShippingDetails.do?invoiceNo=<%=invoiceNo%>&custno=<%=custno%>"><%=invoiceNo%></a></display:column>
     <display:column  property="invDate" title="Invoice Date" format="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
     <display:column  media="html" title="Amount" sortable="true" class="r" headerClass="hr"><%=strCurrency%><%=invAmt %></display:column>
     <display:column  property="dueDate"    title="Due Date" format="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
     <display:column  media="html" title="Balance" sortable="true" class="r" headerClass="hr"><%=strCurrency%><%=balance %></display:column>
     <display:column  title="Balance" sortable="true" property="balance" media="xml csv pdf excel" class="r" headerClass="hr" />
     <display:column  property="followUpDate" title="Follow-up Date" format="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another property for formatting balance (inside of get method) in a bean i.e. balanceHtml with set and get, and then to display as `<display:column property="balanceHtml" sortable="true"/>`.

Comment: In your bean add new property `private String currencyBalance` (balanceHtml in my example above). Then add setter and getter method like: `public String getCurrencyBalance() {return currency+" "+balance.toPlainString()}`. As you have currency in session, add currency to that bean somewhere before i.e. through constructor.